# DataTextField and DataValueField in WPF ComboBox?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010

Is there any way we can have functionality like DataTextField and DataValueField in WPF ComboBox.

I have this query:

```
   Select UID, EmployeeName from tblSystemEmployee;
```

I want to display EmployeeName in the combo box but it keeps displaying UID. Is there any way I can achieve it?  Thank you for your help?

This is how I am populating my dataset:

```
     Try
        cbEmp.Items.Clear()
        Dim QueryString As String = "SELECT UID, EmployeeName FROM tblSystemEmployee"
        Dim drow As DataRow
        drow = Nothing
        dsEmp = New DataSet

        dsEmp = GetResult(QueryString, True)
        If IsValidDataset(dsEmp) Then
            For Each drow In dsEmp.Tables(0).Rows
                cbEmp.Items.Add(drow(0).ToString())

            Next
        End If
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the `DisplayMemberPath` property for the display
and the `SelectedValuePath` property for the value

```
<Combobox DisplayMemberPath="EmployeeName" SelectedValuePath="UID" />
```

Then you can access to whole selected object (e.g. UID, EmployeeName pair) with the `SelectedItem` property but if you just want the UID then the `SelectedValue` property is what you need.

You can learn more about the workings of the properties at MSDN:

- [DisplayMemberPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath.aspx)
- [SelectedValuePath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvaluepath.aspx)

For populating the ComboBox with values you need to set the [ItemsSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource.aspx) property with a list:

Instead of `cbEmp.Items.Clear()` use `cbEmp.ItemsSource = Nothing` and

And

```
If IsValidDataset(dsEmp) Then
        cbEmp.ItemsSource = dsEmp.Tables(0).DefaultView
End If
```

A good intro article about [WPF databinding and comboboxes](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20439/WPF-DataBinding).

Comment: I did as you said. It does not display anything for me. Here is the code I am populating the dataset,

Comment: Please look at the question where I have added the data set code. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The properties you are looking for are: [`DispalyMemberPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath.aspx) and [`SelectedValuePath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvaluepath.aspx).